# Why isn't my entity updated when I make the test Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testing, transactional

Given this class with two tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:config/application-test.properties")
public class AccountDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private AccountDao accountDao;

    @Test
    public void getEmail() {
        User user = new User();
        userDao.save(user);

        Account account = new Account();
        account.setUserId(user.getId());
        account.setEmail("testemail@test.te");
        accountDao.save(account);

        Email email = accountDao.getEmailByAccountId(account.getId());
        assertThat(email, is("testemail@test.te"));
    }

    @Test
    public void deactivate() {
        User user = new User();
        userDao.save(user);

        Account account = new Account();
        account.setUserId(user.getId());
        account.isActive(true);
        accountDao.save(account);

        accountDao.deactivateByUserId(user.getId()); // Query: UPDATE Account SET isActive = false WHERE userId = userId

        Account account2 = accountDao.findById(account.getId());
        assertThat(account2.isActive(), is(false));
    }

}
```

The second one fails if I annotate the class with `@Transactional` (`account2.isActive()` is still `true`). The main difference between both is that I'm updating the entity I save.

Does this mean that I can't run updates on such entities? Why? That doesn't make sense, given that I can insert entities and then fetch them.

I thought it could be due to the transactionality scope (it's DAO level), but then the first test would also fail because the saved `User` wouldn't be available by the time I try to save an `Account`.

Comment: Is there a reason you've written `true` inside the `isActive` method? Does it take a parameter?

Comment: You may need to "flush" after saving/updating your objects and your assertions.

Comment: And then it still won't work. The findById will return the entity from the first level cache which is now out of sync with the database due to the query based update. In the same way the first method doesn't test a thing, it only tests if the email was set on the object not if it was persisted in the database.

Comment: @Norsk There are two methods. `isActive()` is a getter, and `isActive(boolean)` is a setter.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yep, the first test was broken, pretty stupid. I fixed it (edited question), and still get the same results. Is the difference then that in the first test I'm querying by a field other than `id` (so not cached) and in the second one by `id` (cached) ?

Comment: Can you post Your dao implementation? How do you obtain session?

Comment: @patrykos91 I don't use `session`, just an `@Autowired` `entityManager`. For `accountDao.getEmailByAccountId()` I use a custom query and for `findById()`, I use `EntityManager.find()`.

Comment: It will still return the entity from the first level cache, it finds an account with that id and reuses it rather then creating a new one. The problem is that you are updating the database with a query hence your entity and the database are out-of-sync.